# Is this exponential-sized vertex cover problem in P?

Tags: np-complete, vertex-cover

> Suppose P $\neq$ NP.  Prove or disprove if language is in P using a reduction or an algorithm:
>
> $$ \left\{ \left(G = (V,E), k, 0^{2^{|V|}} \right) \mid (G,k) \in VC \right\} $$

Suppose I have the this input $00000000$ I can construct a TM which calculates the number of vertices by applying log operation. So for this example $\log_28 = 3$ I have a graph with 3 vertices.
For this case I need to check if $k$ applies to these vertices.
This can be done in $v\choose k$ operations. I think because it can be done in polynomial time the language is in P.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?  How fast is the trivial vertex cover algorithm compared to the input size of an instance of your problem?

Comment: In the title you ask whether that language is in P, then in question itself you ask whether it is in NP. You realize that being in one set doesn't exclude membership from the other, right?

Comment: @PålGD I am asking if my direction is valid considering this is a a form of VC which is NPC.

Comment: @Steven I understand. but by exercise criteria P not equal to NP. so if I proove it is in NP then it can't be in P. Or so I think...

Comment: Two sets can intersect without being equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, if $L \in \mathsf{TIME}(f(n))$ and $f(n)$ is a reasonable function then the following language is in $\mathsf{P}$:
$$
L' = \{ (x,0^{f(|x|)}) : x \in L \}.
$$
Indeed, given an input $(x,0^m)$, we first check that $m = 0^{f(|x|)}$ (that's why we need $f$ to be *reasonable*, an informal notion which can be formalized if need be), and then we run the algorithm for $L$ witnessing that it is in $\mathsf{TIME}(f(n))$. Since the input has length larger than $f(n)$, the latter part actually runs in linear time.

In your case, $L$ is *vertex cover*, which can be solved in time $2^n$, where $n$ is the number of vertices in the graph (in this regard, your example doesn't quite correspond to the general case above, but the idea is the same). So your $L'$ is in $\mathsf{P}$.

Note that the assumption $\mathsf{P}\neq\mathsf{NP}$ makes no difference here – you can prove that your language is in $\mathsf{P}$ unconditionally.

---

In the comments, you are worried that since vertex cover is NP-complete, you have just shown that P=NP. But your language is not vertex cover, and (assuming P≠NP), it is not NP-hard. You can reduce vertex cover to your language by sending an instance $(G,k)$ of vertex cover to an instance $(G,k,0^{2^{|V|}})$ of your problem, but this reduction doesn't run in polynomial time, since the output is exponentially long.